# Sound in Ubuntu 12.10 on Chromebook

Tags: 12.10, sound, alsa

I've got an HP Chromebook 14 that I've rooted and [installed Ubuntu via Crouton](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343) (upgraded to 12.10) and most things are working nicely.

One issue that I am having trouble solving relates to sound. I've got sound output that I can control via the individual app (e.g. Youtube), but when trying to control the volume via the built-in xfce4-mixer, I get the following error:

> GStreamer was unable to detect any sound devices. Some sound system
>   specific GStreamer packages may be missing. It may also be a
>   permissions problem.

Opening a terminal, I can run the `alsamixer` and control the volume levels. It is reporting back that the card is CRAS. I'd love to be able to do it from XFCE and the built-in mixer.

I've tried re-installing the GStreamer packages, but no luck. It seems like I am close but not sure where to go from here.

On a maybe unrelated note, plugging headphones into the headphone jack in Ubuntu also does not stop the sound from coming from the speakers and nothing comes through the headphones. Switching back to ChromeOs, everything works as expected, so I think that it's a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an Acer chromebook running an xfce desktop using the same method that you probably used.  I was able to get audio working with the panel audio mixer plugin by installing `pulseaudio` and then starting it from terminal with `pulseaudio --start`.
After a reboot, everything worked as expected.